# Tortoise SVN add folder without files issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I use tortoise client svn in my machine. When I click add context menu on a new folder from tortoise svn, I can add a folder only without files under this folder. I don't know why. I would like to get files with folder when I click the add of tortoise svn. How can I do this? Thanks all.

Comment: Just so I understand the question correctly.. Are you saying you have a checked out folder on your computer, i.e. `C:/users/zanhtet/myproject` and you have a folder `myfolder` with a bunch of files and you're attempting to add and commit them into the repository? What do you mean by "I can add a folder only without files under this folder"?

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for reply. Let say that I create a folder and some files under this folder. I want to add this folder and files to repository. So, I click add button of tortoise svn in context menu of the folder. There will be shown a dialog. Normally, there should be folder and the files in this dialog box. Now, only the folder is showing in dialog box. So, I go to the folder and click add file one by one. So, I would like to add all files and folder in dialog box. How to do it.

Comment: That is strange, the process you described is typically how I do it. Have you tried just doing CTRL + A to highlight everything in the folder and then right clicking and going to **TortoiseSVN > Add...** ?